# Почему не видно переменной вне функции?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему я сделал `return` объекта, но вне функции показывает ошибку, что её не существует?

```
function getParametres() {
    let valueName = document.getElementById('nameCard').value
    let valuePrice = document.getElementById('priceCard').value
    let valueSrcImg = document.getElementById('srcImgCard').value
    modalWindow.style.display = 'none'
    let object = {name: valueName, price: valuePrice, src: valueSrcImg}
    setTimeout(createCard, 0)
    
    return object
}
console.log(object)
```

Comment: А почему её должно быть видно? она же В ФУНКЦИИ

Comment: а саму функцию вы не вызываете

Comment: она вызывается, по клику кнопки, просто я не добавил этот код. Она в функции верно, но разве return не позволяет её использовать вне функции?

Comment: @RayOver, `return` ничего не позволяет и ничего не запрещает использовать. Он просто _возвращает значение_. Если ты сохранишь это значение куда-то - ты, очевидно, сможешь его использовать.

Comment: @Grundy Я создал переменную в которую добавил эту функцию. В итоге обьект действительно теперь показывается через console.log, но только ключи, их значения же -- пусты.

Comment: _Я создал переменную в которую добавил эту функцию._ - непонятно, что ты имеешь ввиду.

Comment: @Grundy ну, короч, асинхронщина, очевидно)  но пока сам автор не покажет весь код - мы не убедимся в этом)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не обязательно, может быть просто не туда или не то присваивал :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> она вызывается, по клику кнопки, просто я не добавил этот код. Она в
> функции верно, но разве return не позволяет её использовать вне
> функции?

так после нажатия на кнопку и запускайте консоль,также дополнительно нужно куда-то присвоить результат функции, иначе вы не сможете к нему обратиться

```js
function getParametres() {
    let valueName = 'text'
    let valuePrice = 'text'
    let valueSrcImg = 'text'
    
    let object = {name: valueName, price: valuePrice, src: valueSrcImg}
    
    
    return object
}
 let obj = getParametres()
 console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался в своих ошибках.